# Possible to GEO target an iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I really don't know what to call this so i am struggling to even search for it. Basically I have a website that targets many different countries, I currently have an iframe on the page that is only really useful to people in the UK, is it possible for me to check browser GEO location and display a different iframe depending on country of the user?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ipinfo](http://ipinfo.io/) to discover the user's location and then change the iframe's url:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    $('iframe').attr('src', url + '?country=' + response.country);
}, "jsonp");
```